# calculate numeric value based on character variables

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset

```
Date       Company      Sales
Jan05     Coca-Cola      256    
Jan05     Lowes          70
Jan05     Apple          90    
Feb05     McDonald       456
Feb05     Apple          89
Feb05     Microsoft      876
March05
April05
. 
.
.
Jan06     Apple          678
Jan06     Lowes          87
Jan06     Intel          56 
Feb06     McDonald       67
Feb06     Apple          281
Feb06     Barclays       876
March06
April06
.
.
.
Jan07    Apple          567
Jan07    Lowes          76
Jan07    Intel          87
Feb07    TJmax          678
Feb07    McDonald       765
Feb07    Astraz         67
March07   
April06
.
.
.
May15
```

As you can see, the data set starts from January 2005 and continues all the way up to May 2015. Each month of the year has hundreds of Companies with different Sales volumes.

I am trying to calculate a 12 month sales growth rate for each Company that did buy on at least 13 consecutive months (i.e. a span of 12 months from start to end month). 
If multiple periods with a span of 12 months are available, I want the medium.

A few examples:

- If a company *only* buys on *jan2005, feb2005, ...till... jan2006*, the growth rate is `(jan2006 sales = jan2005 sales ) / jan2005 sales`
- If a company buys on *multiple disjoint periods with a span of 12 months*, like *jan2005, ...till... jan2006* **and** jan2008, ...till... jan2009 **and**  jan2010, ...till... jan2011,the growth rate is the median of the individual gowth rate
- If a company _only buys on 14 consecutive months, like *jan2005, ...till... feb2006* the growth rate is the median of those for *jan2005, ...till... jan2006* and *feb2005, ...till... feb2006*

Comment: The following information may be required to clarify your requirements: 1.Are the time period between each "Sales" data of the same company always a multiple of 12 months?    2.What's the format of the "Date" variable?

Comment: @user2916331. I want to calculate a 12 month growth rate, so it has to be companies 12 months apart. So a from Jan05 to Jan06, Jan06-Jan07, Jan07 to Jan08..and the same goes for all  other months. 2: The date format I have is numerical.

Comment: Is 12 month growth rate the arithmetic mean growth per month over 12 consecutive years? (i.e. over 11 differences)

Comment: And another question: Should I see growth as difference or as percentage?

Answer (score 0):

**Reading the data with an informat:**
 - In SAS, the only data types are fixed width strings and double precision numericals.
 - What looks like a date variable is actually a number (i.e. the number of days since 1jan1960) with an associated print format. I used `ddmmyy9`.
 - To read in a date from a string representation, you use an informat. I used `monyy5.`;

```
data theInput;
    infile theFile firstobs=2;
    format Date ddmmyy9. Company $12. Sales 8.;
    input Date monyy5. Company $ Sales;
;
run;
```

**Sort**;

```
proc sort data=theInput out=reOrdered;
    by Company Date;
run;
```

**Get individual growth rates**;

```
data individualRates;
    set reOrdered;
    by Company Date;
    format From Till monyy7.;

    from = lag12(Date);
    oldSales = lag12(Sales);

    if lag12(Company) EQ Company 
    and INTCK('month', from, Date) EQ 12 then do;
        till = Date;
        rate =  (Sales - oldSales) / oldSales;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

**Calculate the medians**;

```
proc means data=individualRates noprint;
    by Company;
    output out=medianRates median(rate)=medianRate;
run;
```

Comment: by 12 month growth rate I mean the 12 month median growth rate.

Comment: Sorry, but I will only continue programming when I am sure what you want, so let me pose a few specific questions. **Are** you aware medians is not the same as mean? **If** you have data for say **jan2010 till dec2010**, do you disqualify the case because you only have 11 growth rates? **If** you have data for **jan2010 till feb2011**, do you want the median growth rate for jan2010 till jan2011 **and** the medium growth rate for feb2010 till feb2011 on separate output rows?

Comment: My data runs from Jan 2005 until May 2015. I want to calculate median for Jan2005 to January 2006, February 05 to February 06, March 05 to March 06 and so on. Such that each row has a median growth rate for each month of the year.

Comment: And you are aware a median of twelve values is not one twelfth of the sum, but the mid in between the 6th lagest and the 7th largest value?

Comment: I hope that by now you understand you should be **MUCH CLEARER when posing a question**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I want to do is basically calculate a growth rate per company from Jan05 to Jan06, Feb05 to Feb06...then for March, then for April...then Jan06 to Jan07, Feb06 to Feb07. That will give me growth rate values across companies. Then I am going to take the median of those growth rates. Does this make sense? 

So basically I need a column that has growth rate values per company...and then I'll just take the median of those growth rate. 
So it'll be a median of the growth rate and not the growth rate of the median as I mistakenly said earlier.